# OpenID delegation and <html> tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, openid, design

I have added the OpenID delegation code for VeriSign PIP to [my website](http://nullroute.eu.org/~grawity/), and it is accepted on all websites except the Stack Overflow series. All attempts to add `http://nullroute.eu.org/~grawity/` (my website's address) as an OpenID to Server Fault, Super User, or the rest result in:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> **No OpenID endpoint found.**

It seems that Stack Overflow is looking for the `<link>` tags inside `<html><head>`. This fails, because my `index.html` does not have a `<html>` tag. (Optional in all HTML versions.) This has been already noticed by other users, and confirmed by me: I temporarily added `<html>` and stackoverflow.com happily accepted my new OpenID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE sites authenticate using DotNetOpenAuth, the bug-tracker for which can be found [here](http://trac.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/report/3).