# Consecutive upvoted answers badge

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, badge-request

I reckon that consistently answering questions well should be rewarded, but is the following a good idea?

My idea is to award a bronze, silver and gold set of badges for getting (nett) upvotes on consecutive answers (and quite possibly questions).  So that if you look at your 'recent' view of answers there is a run of positive numbers.

Something like, if 10 answers in a row get (nett) upvotes you are awarded a bronze 'consistent answers' badge, for 20 you get silver and 50 you get gold.  This could also apply to questions.

I realise that this may encourage people to delete some of their answers that have received no upvotes but that may not be a bad side effect.  Encouraging the deletion of questions with no upvotes is a different matter.

This could also be extended to accepted answers - with lower thresholds, naturally.

As a couple of plus points for implementing this feature, this badge would already allow people to self-monitor their progress reasonably simply (I know there have been a few requests for badge progress monitors in the past) and the sql query to count runs of consecutive upvotes is reasonably simple (but may make a good SO queston!).

As a couple of points of interest, in the 70 answers I've made on SO I've had a run of five and another run of six consecutive upvoted answers - so I would not yet qualify for this badge.  I searched for 'Consecutive upvoted answers' to find duplicates - but there did not seem to be anything similar, but if there is a duplicate could someone mention the search they used to find it?

Comment: I get the feeling (?!) that there is no support for this question - I will delete it if that is the case.

Comment: 1 upvote / 7 downvotes - is that a no then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally wouldn't do it:

- Too overlapped with several existing badges.
- Discourages risky/controversial
  answers.
- A bit arbitrary - gives too much weight to one single "bad" answer.

Comment: Damn, after 2 hours with no activity I'd despaired of any response and was holding out for tumbleweed!

Comment: I think it is more creditworthy than 'nice answer', for example - which could be deprecated.  Risky/controversial/bad answers can be deleted.

Comment: @amelvin: controversial answers are **not** bad.

Comment: @Phoshi: Didn't say that controversial answers are necessarily bad - just that they *can* be deleted if they don't get upvotes.

Comment: @amelvin Sorry... Tumbleweed is a bit hard to get anyway... keep on trying :)

Comment: @Daniel - Might have to content myself with a 'Peer Pressure'!

Comment: Tumbleweed on meta would be nigh impossible, since there are few enough posts here that it's easy to just monitor the front page and read everything that comes in. Yesterday's work day (for me) only saw five new posts for the entire day!

Comment: @Ether: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/tumbleweed. Some of winner questions seem to be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45725/improving-community-wiki-answer-navigation, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45561/openid-delegation-and-html-tag, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27798/careers-field-separator-punctuation...

Comment: And now @Daniel taunts me with his tumbleweed!  Enough already.

Comment: @amelvin I _don't_ have Tumbleweed. I answered to @Ether's impossibility conjecture by linking to the page where _other_ users who have Tumbleweed are listed. (That said, every mention of that badge reminds me of the The Jesus and Mary Chain song "Tumbledown".)

Comment: @Daniel I understood really, its only meta, badges/rep aren't important - and it wouldn't surprise me if there was a hidden unicorn badge somewhere here!  I would +1 for the J&MC reference (but I already upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 5):

This is likely to backfire by discouraging people from answering questions in the less well-known tags (which get a lot fewer upvotes).

Comment: +1 Possible I guess, but I would have thought that great answers get upvoted in just about any category - even the less-well-travelled-ones.

Comment: On the less-travelled ones there will be less people who know it's a great answer.