# Consistently Good Answers Badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request

So, I've this idea for a badge. I have observed what I feel is a negative behavior on Stack, that could potentially be reduced by the introduction of a badge that rewards the opposite behavior. And I thought I would post the idea here for discussion.

### The Negative Behavior ( ? )

Recently I've noticed that a fair number of users post more-than regular answers to questions in the hopes of 'fishing' for up-votes, without necessarily spending any time reading the question or putting any time or thought into the answer. So, we end up with answers that are either unrelated or just wrong. Unless those answers receive down-votes, there is no incentive for them to remove said answer.

### The Solution

The idea, is to introduce a `Consistent Quality` badge which would be rewarded to users with over `x` answers and an average of over `y` votes. A suggested starting point (for a low entry badge) might be over 25 answers, with an average vote score of greater than 1. You could potentially have other greater badges for higher averages but then you'll fall into problems where users might be encouraged to delete useful answers just because they don't have up-votes.

---

I've managed to find one similar proposal on Meta for a badge for *consecutive* upvoted answers but, as pointed out, this would discourage people from posting potentially controversial answers that could otherwise be useful or relevant.

[Consecutive upvoted answers badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/consecutive-upvoted-answers-badge)

To start the discusion, is the negative behavior described above even really a problem? Would the badge be an interesting/fun addition anyway? Are there any unthought of issues that this could cause?

Comment: In my opinion, consistent highly upvoted answers does not mean that they are good answers.

Answer (score 4):

I understand what you are saying, but I fear this may have more downsides than upsides

## Upvoted poor answers are the problem

Votes are how we measure usefulness, if poor quality answers are getting upvotes (which does happen, but I think its rare) then *that* is the problem. Any solution that attempts to correct the problem without addressing that is unlikely to succeed. I don't think this is currently too huge a problem but the solution is to downvote bad answer (rather than just ignoring them).

## This can punish high quality answers to unusual questions

Some of the answers I'm most proud of are 0 or 1 vote answers, they are low score because they are to an unusual technique in an unusual technology (*resists urge to link to some of them*). They helped the OP (who may have been a 1-rep user), probably a few people from google and no-one else, but that doesn't mean they weren't high quality. If I really cared about badges (which I really really don't) then I might have been put off answering some of these.

Comment: "poor quality answers are getting upvotes (which does happen, but I think its rare)" - when you dig into Data.SE a bit (with a query such as [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/102768/marginal-short-answers?StartDate=2014.01.01&EndDate=2014.01.31&AnswerScoreMax=2&AnswerScoreMin=1&AnswerLength=200)) you will find that they often get upvotes.

Comment: @MichaelT Possibly it more a hope that they are rare, but I would argue short != low quality (necissarily)

Comment: Its hard to do a query with a clause of `where a.postquality = "sucks" and a.votes > 0` - so post length is a proxy for it.  And I was only pulling one month of data with scores of 1-2 (not 3+).  The thing is, theres a lot of questions that get upvotes that really make you wonder "why?!"  I contend that upvotes on poor answers are not rare at all.

Comment: @MichaelT I really want that to exist! Regardless, my main point was that "it doesn't matter if they are rare or not", its the high scores on bad posts that needs to be corrected, any tinkering with badges isn't going to help while that remains

Comment: There is a little bit of an issue with using the poor upvoting as a reason for not implementing a badge. We already have badges that rely on the up-vote system, and it's also a problem that may never be solvable because you can't control the user input completely without taking voting out of the hands of the users, which defeats the point in the voting system entirely. Punishing people for posting good answers to poorly viewed questions is a genuine concern.